# Image avoiding the cursor using Javascript and HTML?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

so im trying to make an image move away from the mouse everytime the mouse comes near it. I found a code here:http://jsfiddle.net/karalamalar/atNva/ but im having trouble making it work. I think im implementing it wrong into my webpage as it is my 1st time working with html, css and javascript. Can someone let me know what im doing wrong and how i would go about fixing it (if any).

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>My Websites</title>
        <style type="text/css">
            th, td {
                padding: 15px;
                table-layout: fixed;
                width: 180px;
                z-index:100;
                padding: 0px;
            }

            td {
                text-align: center;
                font-family:"Times New Roman", Helvetica, sans-serif; 
                font-size: 15pt;
                border-radius:5px
            }

            .center{
                position: fixed;
                top: 50%;
                left: 50%;
                transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
            }

            .bottomright{
                position: fixed;
                bottom:-2%;
                right:0.5%  
            }

            a {
                color:#00003D;
                text-decoration:none
            }

            a:hover {
                color: orange;
                font-size: 105%;
            }

            img.DoorTop{
                width: 100%;
                height: 50%;
                position: fixed;
                top: 0;
                left: 0;
                z-index: 100000;
                -webkit-animation: moveUp 5s forwards; 
                animation: moveUp 5s forwards;
                -webkit-animation-delay: 2s; 
                animation-delay: 2s;
            }

            @keyframes moveUp {
                from {top:0%;}
                to {top:-100%;}
            }

            @-webkit-keyframes moveUp {
                from {top:0%;}
                to {top:-100%;}
            }

            img.DoorBottom{
                width: 100%;
                height: 50%;
                position: fixed;
                bottom: 0;
                left: 0;
                z-index: 100000;
                -webkit-animation: moveDown 5s forwards; 
                animation: moveDown 5s forwards;
                -webkit-animation-delay: 2s; 
                animation-delay: 2s;
            }

            @keyframes moveDown {
                from {bottom:0%;}
                to {bottom:-100%;}
            }

            @-webkit-keyframes moveDown {
                from {bottom:0%;}
                to {bottom:-100%;}
            }
            .circle {
                background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
                border: 5px solid rgba(0,183,229,0.9);
                opacity: .9;
                border-right: 5px solid;
                border-left: 5px solid ;
                border-radius: 50px;
                box-shadow: 0 0 35px #2187e7;
                width: 30px;
                height: 30px;
                margin: 0 auto;
                animation: spinPulse 1s infinite linear;
                -webkit-animation: spinPulse 1s infinite linear;
            }

            .circle1 {
                background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
                border: 5px solid rgba(0,183,229,0.9);
                opacity: .9;
                border-left: 5px solid;
                border-right: 5px solid;
                border-radius: 50px;
                box-shadow: 0 0 15px #2187e7;
                width: 10px;
                height: 10px;
                margin: 0 auto;
                position: relative;
                top: -30px;
                animation: spinoffPulse 1s infinite linear;
                -webkit-animation: spinoffPulse 1s infinite linear;
            }

            @keyframes spinPulse {
                0% {
                    transform: rotate(160deg);
                    opacity: 0;
                    box-shadow: 0 0 1px #2187e7;
                }
                50% {
                    transform: rotate(145deg);
                    opacity: 1;
                }
                100% {
                    transform: rotate(-320deg);
                    opacity: 0;
                }   
            }

            @keyframes spinoffPulse {
                0% {
                    transform: rotate(0deg);
                }
                100% {
                    transform: rotate(360deg);
                }
            }

            @-webkit-keyframes spinPulse {
                0% {
                    -webkit-transform: rotate(160deg);
                    opacity: 0;
                    box-shadow: 0 0 1px #2187e7;
                }
                50% {
                    -webkit-transform: rotate(145deg);
                    opacity: 1;
                }
                100% {
                    -webkit-transform: rotate(-320deg);
                    opacity: 0;
                }   
            }

            @-webkit-keyframes spinoffPulse {
                0% {
                    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
                }

                100% {
                    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
                }
            }       

            img.growturn {
                transition: width 2s, height 2s, transform 2s;
            }

            img.growturn:hover {
                width: 400px;
                height: 400px;
                transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
            }

            body { position: relative; }
            #img { position: relative; }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body id="body" style="background:url(webdata/images/index/background.png) no-repeat; background-attachment: fixed; background-size:100% 100%;">

        <img src="webdata/images/index/emblem.png" width="50" height="50" alt="Grey Square" id="img" style="z-index:900"/>
        <script>jQuery(function($) {
            $('#img').mouseover(function() {
            var dWidth = $(document).width() - 100, // 100 = image width
            dHeight = $(document).height() - 100, // 100 = image height
            nextX = Math.floor(Math.random() * dWidth),
            nextY = Math.floor(Math.random() * dHeight);
            $(this).animate({ left: nextX + 'px', top: nextY + 'px' });
            });
        });
        </script>

        <div>
            <img class="DoorTop" src="webdata/images/index/topDoor.png" alt="topDoor">
            <img class="DoorBottom" src="webdata/images/index/bottomDoor.png" alt="bottomDoor">
        </div>

        <div class="center">
            <table class="button">
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="4">
                        <img class="growturn" src="webdata/images/index/emblem.png" alt="" height="40" width="40" style="position:absolute; left:28%; top:6%">
                        <p style="font-family:'Lucida Sans Unicode', 'Lucida Grande', sans-serif; font-size: 15pt; color: white;">PROJECT <strong>COSC</strong>2206</p>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="4" style="font-family:Geneva, 'Book Antiqua', Palatino, serif; font-size: 40pt; color: orange">WELCOME TO My WYBSITE</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="4" style="font-family:Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 9pt; color:#C2F0FF; letter-spacing: 1px; padding: 20px">Welcome to Project COSC2206. All assignments can be viewed below once they become available or simply return to the iTool's.</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td style="background-color:#00CCFF;"><a href="#">Itool</a></td>
                    <td style="background-color:#00CCFF;"><a href="classified.html">Assignment 2</a></td>
                    <td style="background-color:#00CCFF;"><a href="classified.html">Assignment 3</a></td>
                    <td style="background-color:#00CCFF;"><a href="classified.html">Assignment 4</a></td>
                </tr>
            </table>  
        </div>  



        <a href="http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fcoscvm23.cs.laurentian.ca%2F;outline=1" target="_blank">
            <img src="webdata/images/index/HTML5_Badge.png" alt="" width="28" height="27" style="position: fixed; float: left; left: 7px; bottom: 5px;">
        </a>    
        <a href="http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/check/referer" target="_blank">
            <img src="webdata/images/index/CSS3.png" alt="" width="31" height="31" style="position: fixed; float: left; left: 35px; bottom: 2px;">
        </a>

        <div class="bottomright">
            <div class="circle"></div>
            <div class="circle1"></div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: One problem is that you are writing jQuery code but never included the jQuery library in your page.

Comment: how would i include the library?

Comment: This is off topic, due to a typographical error.

Answer (score 1):

If that's the entire code for you webpage, you'll need to include jQuery.  I like to use Google's, but you can host it yourself as well:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Edit: you could put the code above anywhere in the head, and you should be good to go.